# Is it possible to load software to a microcontroller and then use it in a different circuit?

Tags: microcontroller

I am working on a project that requires using software loaded to a microcontroller in addition to a potentiometer to control a 5 V servo motor.

My understanding is that this can be done with a Texas Instrument Launchpad. What I can't understand is how can I use this same microcontroller without having to use the same Launchpad.

Is there a way to use the Launchpad just to program it with the necessary code and then use the chip in other non-Launchpad based circuit configuration? Is there a way to program it without even using the Launchpad?

Comment: If by "load" you mean to flash it into internal non-volatile memory of the chip - then yes, it is totally possible. And yes, it is possible to use the launchpad as a programmer.

Comment: yes,  i  believe i came across the word "load"  alot  along  with "flash."   I am having trouble understanding how the program is able to continue running on the chip if it is no longer attached to the Launchpad's emulator circuit.  How is that physically possible ?

Comment: In general, yes, and this is how they were originally designed to be used, before in-circuit programming became popular. You would buy microcontrollers, put them through a programming device, then solder them into your circuit. If you paid extra, the manufacturer would program them for you.. However, I don't know about the Launchpad specifically.

Comment: @keikaku It is not "running" on the detached microcontroller, it is stored on it, just like programs are stored on your computer hard drive even when your computer is unplugged. These micros have internal memory, which is non-volatile, meaning retaining it's content even when not powered.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can do that. If your Launchpad has a socketed DIP MCU, you can just pull it out after programming and plug it into a different circuit. The program remains on the chip. (You should turn the Launchpad off before removing the MCU from it, of course.)

You can also use the Launchpad's integrated programmer and connect it to a different target circuit via jumper wires. (There's a header for that on the PCB.)

Comment: thanks for the comment.  i will ask the same thing to you.  I am having trouble understanding how the program is able to continue running on the chip if it is no longer attached to the Launchpad's emulator circuit. How is that physically possible ?

Comment: @keikaku Because the chip is an independent device. As long as it receives proper power supply, its I/O pins will react according to the program. It's possible to program and reprogram it (if it's not one time programmable) on your own DIY PCB with a USB connection and a PC. (on which a loading software must be installed).

Comment: I just  remembered a point I forgot to mention, which added to my misunderstanding.  On the Texas Instrument Launchpad, there is a crystal oscillator. So, based on all the useful answers I am reading so far, am I to understand that after I use the Launchpad to program the chip and then remove it from the Launchpad and put it in a different circuit, that the crystal oscillator is something that I do not need ??  I had the impression that the crystal oscillator of the Launchpad circuit is  what helps the chip to do its job ?

Comment: The external crystal is only needed if you use it in your program. You should know best whether you configured the microcontroller to use it or not. The Launchpad also doesn't contain an "emulator", but rather a debugger. The program is fully contained on the microcontroller chip, you can just "poke" it from the outside with the debugger as long as it's attached to the Launchpad. When you take it out, the program can still run, you just can't debug it anymore.